# Training with a max-margin ranking loss converges to useless solution

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, ranking, loss-functions

I want to train a neural network to predict real-valued scores $s(x)$ for items $x$.

I use a dataset of examples $(x_p,X_n)$ where $x_p$ is a "positive" item that should be assigned a higher score than all "negative" items in $X_n$. I train the network with stochastic gradient descent minimizing a max-margin loss:

$L(x_p,X_n) = max(0, 1 + \max_{x \in X_n}{s(x)} - s(x_p))$

The function $s$ is a multi-layered perceptron with parameters $\theta$.

The problem is that this approach often converges to a very useless solution: Starting with a loss higher than 1, gradient descent just updates the network by decreasing $\theta$ further and further. Thereby, the scores $s(x)$ of both the positive and negative instances become smaller, as well as their difference and thus the loss. The loss then coverges to 1 and the model predicts almost the same score for every element.

Instead, I would want the network to learn to separate positive and negative items by predicting scores such that $s(x_p) > 1 + score(x_n)$.

Playing around with my data, I made the following observations:

- When training on a very small subset, it works as expected.
- The more data I add, the more often it fails to learn and converges to the useless solution.
- Whether that happens or not heavily depends on how the weights were initialized (i.e. on the random seed).

Is there anything I'm missing here that would make the training more stable? Some sort of regularization? Or is there an issue with my setup?

Answer (score 3):

In here a year too late, but try adding a softmax layer:

$$ softmax(x_i) = \frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}{e^{x_j}}} $$

This constrains the output scores so that they sum to 1, regularizing the model to "choose" a ranking, rather than forcing them all to zero.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is widely recognized in the instance of training embeddings for Knowledge graph embeddings for link prediction. Even though it might be tangential I think it complements the answer already posted.

In the TransE paper (https://www.utc.fr/~bordesan/dokuwiki/_media/en/transe_nips13.pdf) they solve it by constraining the entity embeddings norm to always sum to 1.

$$ \lVert \mathbf{E_i} \rVert= 1$$

> "the L2-norm of the embeddings of the entities is 1. This constraint is important
>   for our model, as it is for previous embedding-based methods [3, 6, 2], because it prevents the training process to trivially minimize L by artificially increasing entity embeddings norms."

It's also explained similarly in the paper [3] they refer to (Learning Structured Embeddings of Knowledge Bases, https://ronan.collobert.com/pub/matos/2011_knowbases_aaai.pdf)

> "The normalization in step (4) helps remove scaling freedoms from our model (where, for example, E can be made smaller while Rlhs and Rrhs can be made larger and still give the same output)" Where E is one of the embedding matrices to be learned."

Check out this pytorch implementation for better understanding on how this is implemented in practice, https://github.com/xjdwrj/TransE-Pytorch/blob/master/TransE.py

In the forward pass method:

```
pH_embeddings = F.normalize(pH_embeddings, 2, 1)
```

Let me know if something is incorrect/off.